# Finding tangent vector to intersection of two curves

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The question is as follows:

Let $C$ be the intersection curve of two surfaces defined by $x^2 + y^3 - z^4 = 1$ and $z^3 + zx + xy = 3$. Find the tangent vector of $C$ at the point $(1, 1, 1)$.

I'm not sure as to how to approach this question but would setting the two equations equal and then forming a parametric equation out of the result to get the tangent vector be an appropriate approach?

Edit: My approach seems to be algebraically very intensive, anyone have any clever ways to do this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Setting equations equal throws away information. Find the normal vectors to each of the surfaces at $(1,1,1)$. The tangent vector to $C$ must be in both tangent planes, hence perpendicular to both normal vectors. Can you find it?

Comment: Okay, so find the Grad of each function at point (1,1,1) and then cross product of these two vectors to get the tangent vector?

Comment: Perfect! Go do it! :)